# C# и HTTPS POST запрос

Tags: c#, post, https

Как можно реализовать **HTTPS** POST-запрос, имеющий `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` шифр?

Поскольку при передаче данных как таковое `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` шифрование не используется, я подозреваю, что хватит лишь включить работу с сертификатами.

Но как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы имеете в виду как настраиваются алгоритмы шифрования в Windows, то они настраиваются так:

- Сервер, к которому адресуется запрос поддерживает несколько алгоритмов шифрования.
- Клиент, который отправляет запрос, также поддерживает несколько алгоритмов шифрования.
- В ходе установки шифрованного канала сервер и клиенту договариваются, какой алгоритм использовать.

Чтобы быть уверенным, что будет использоваться именно TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, можно на сервере отключить поддержку всех алгоритмов кроме этого. Или сделать то же самое на клиенте. Или и на сервере и на клиенте.

Есть удобная программа IISCrypto.  https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/ в ней можно отключить старые протоколы и поднять приоритет использования тех или иных алгоритмов. Недостаток программы в том, что она не разделяет протоколы для Server (входящие соединения) и для Client (исходящие). Протокол включается или отключается и для Server и для Client,

Если настроить исходящие соединения (Client), как требуется. То все клиенты (исходящие соединения из текущий операционной системы) будут использовать заданные настройки. В том числе и запросы из программы на C#.

Comment: Нет. Мне надо отправить запрос с методом POST, протоколом HTTPS и шифрованием TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA. Но за вашу информацию все равно спасибо.